# Will learning Titanium Appcelerator improve my understanding of NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, titanium, appcelerator

I am learning how to build mobile JavaScript Application in Titanium Appcelerator. I am reading some of the documentation and they are now using the V8 Engine as their JS interpreter for Android. And some of the approaches are a clone of Node. Can I get a clearer understanding of Node by learning how to build App using Titanium Appcelerator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Titanium is an API around the native iOs, Android, etc libraries for building mobile apps.  Most casual users will never delve into the internals of whatever js engine Titanium uses under the covers.

You will learn more about node.js by building node.js apps.  If you want to learn about v8, you can always [download the source](http://code.google.com/p/v8/).  [Same for node.js](https://github.com/joyent/node).

Answer (score 0):

Learning Titanium will not help you 'learn' node.js or V8, but the advanced JavaScript programming patterns in both (callbacks, passing functions as first class objects,etc. ) will be similar.